# Created a package.json file, but getting dependency errors when running npm install

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm

I know this is a common question and I tried researching on here, but none of the answers have seemed to help me thus far.

I am following this tutorial to learn node, and after I try to install the package.json I received the following errors:

```
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! path /Users/salvi/Desktop/nodejs1/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno -2

npm ERR! package.json ENOENT, open '/Users/salvi/Desktop/nodejs1/package.json'
npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/salvi/Desktop/nodejs1/node_modules/npm-debug.log



// package.json

{
    "name": "node-api",
    "main": "server.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "~4.0.0",
        "mongoose": "~3.6.13",
        "body-parser": "~1.0.1"
    }
}
```

I know I have node installed because of checking the version, and Im running this command in the terminal in the root of the application. Any help appreciated!

EDIT: I am receiving the following now when I run npm install:

`npm install
-bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory`

https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4

Comment: How did you install node.js ?

Comment: `npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory` A you shure that package.json in your current directory?

Comment: using the website I just clicked the big green install button

Comment: I am sure that I am in the directory that holds the package.json, but now Im not getting errors I get this instead:

```/usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory```

Comment: http://imgur.com/xsbk0Qz

Comment: ok I reinstalled node and now Im getting the same error messages as before: 

Node was installed at

   /usr/local/bin/node

npm was installed at

   /usr/local/bin/npm

Yet it is saying it cant find that directory!

Comment: Where did you run `npm install`? Can you show the folder structure of your node project?

Comment: give the output of `echo $PATH`

Comment: please see the image above, that shows everything

Comment: /Users/salvi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin:/Users/salvi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/bin:/Users/salvi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/salvi/.rbenv/shims:/Users/salvi/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/ImageMagick/bin:/Users/salvi/.rvm/bin

Comment: is this all because I use RVM?

Comment: Nope your PATH seems fine, but you run your npm install from node_modules directory not from your project directory, `cd ..`

Comment: I get the same errors unfortunately if I switch to my app directory

Comment: http://imgur.com/9zr0Q93 Error when trying to run npm from root directory

Comment: give the output of `ls` in node project directory

Comment: sure:

```nodejs1 salvi$ ls
models  node_modules npm-debug.log```

Comment: As we can see, there `paсkage.json` no in the project folder. Create it by running the command `npm init` in project folder or create your own with a text editor.

Comment: oh! Ok I know whats wrong thanks to your comment. I had the server and package.js in my node_modules folder/directory. OOPS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see, there `paсkage.json` no in the project folder. Create it by running the command `npm init` in project folder or create your own with a text editor.